# how to fill template column with data in RadGrid batch edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, telerik-grid

In my telerik:RadGrid batch-editing,GridTemplateColumn ItemTemplate cannot bind with data.To invoke grid fill method I used bellow syntax.

```
function GridBind(GridID, GridData) {
    var TableView = GridID.get_masterTableView();
    TableView.set_dataSource(GridData); TableView.dataBind();
}
```

My grid TemplateColumn syntax is bellow:

```
                 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Category" DefaultInsertValue="Beverages" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" UniqueName="CategoryID" DataField="CategoryID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
<telerik:RadTextBox ID=" txtCategoryName " runat="server" Width="80px" Text=<%# Eval("CategoryName ") %>  >
                            </telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="CategoryIDDropDown" DataValueField="CategoryID"
                                DataTextField="CategoryName"                            </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

In my above column ItemTemplate **<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>** not bind with data.i don’t like to use method **RadGrid1_RowDataBound** from ClientEvents ,is it possible to invoke this method from my custom function **GridBind()** to bind this item column data or there is available any process to fill data with template column.

```
<ClientSettings>
                <ClientEvents  OnRowDataBound="RadGrid1_RowDataBound"></ClientEvents>
            </ClientSettings>

function RadGrid1_RowDataBound(sender, args) {
                var radTextBox1 = args.get_item().findControl("LastName"); // find control
                radTextBox1.set_value(args.get_dataItem()["txtCategoryName "]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using client-side binding so you must use the RowDataBound event. Server controls and client-side binding are kind of opposite concepts. Thus, server binding expressions cannot be used like this.

Option 2 is to use pure HTML in a ClientItemTemplate with Telerik Kendo binding templates: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/client-side/client-item-template/defaultcs.aspx